# iPhone, iPod touch, iPad developing differences

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ipod-touch

I am developing an application for iPhone 4 that uses the camera, accelerometer and gyroscope. I am wondering if the same app can run on iPod touch last generation. I have a trouble finding an iPhone 4 for testing. And I would like to know if I have to do some code changes if I want to run it on an iPod touch. They both have retina displays and we are not using phone functionalities.

Comment: You should accept some answers by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone 4 camera is higher resolution than the iPod touch camera, but that oughtn't present too much of a problem. The iPod touch shares the accelerometer and gyroscope with the iPhone, so no worries there.

So, it should work, although it is always best to test on as many devices as possible.